# how to show the plot in pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am receiving following error for this code, how can I solve it:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 15
fig = plt.figure ()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

t =  linspace (-2, 2, 100)
x = (1 + t**2) * sin(2 * pi * t)
y = (1 + t**2) * cos(2 * pi * t)
z = t

ax.plot(x, y, z, label='Parametric 3D curve')
ax.legend()
show()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "/home/me/workspace/mysecondpythontest/my1pythontest", line 19, in
>     show() NameError: name 'show' is not defined

Comment: You called a function called `show()`, but it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show()` does not exist.

You need to call `plt.show()`